# Creating and Testing a Firebase Dynamic Link Without Domain?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

My app is in development so i do not have a domain. I am trying to test firebase dynamic links to implement a refer a friend feature. I was using firebase for push notifications before and it was working fine.

I added required implementation for dynamic links to my android project.

When i go to dynamic links on firebase console and click on get started  it wants me to type a domain name.I do not have a domain name.

If i go to hosting on firebase console it shows 2 default domain name. First is with `web.app`, second is with `firebaseapp.com`

If i go back to dynamic links click on get started and type my `web.app` url to the textbox and then write path prefix /referFriend , it shows me a hosting config. Where should i add this configuration ? To my google services.json ? If its googleservices.json where should i add it exactly in that file ?

After i press continue this screen comes out:
[image]

Since i do not own `web.app` what should i do ?

If i do not write /referFriend on previous step, this screen comes out:
[image]

I am very confused about testing this without having a domain name and need an explanation. I do not have firebase.json. I have googleservices.json on android app client, and i have another json file on server side which i used for push notifications before.(it starts with type,project_id,private_key_id,private_key...)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a domain for your app, you can use a free custom page.link subdomain:

eg. `https://[YOUR_APP_NAME].page.link/summer-sale` if you wanted summer-sale dynamic link

Create your free subdomain in the Firebase console.

Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/#how_does_it_work

Where? Goto `Your Project` > `Grow` Section > `Dynamic Links`